# Error with Firebase and ionic 3 application

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, observable

I have this error on my ionic 3 and angular5 application.

Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Type 'any[]' is not assignable to
            type 'Menu'. Property 'categories' is missing in type 'any[]'.

I'm trying to get data from a FireBase database.
My model:

```
import { Category } from "./category.model";

export interface Menu {
    key?: string;
    categories: Category[]
}

import { Dish } from "./dish.model";

export interface Category {
    key? : string,
    category: string,
    description: string
    dishes: Dish[],
    imageName: string
}

export interface Dish {
    key?: string,
    imageName: string;
    name: string,
    description: string,
    price: number
}
```

DataService:

```
@Injectable()
export class MenuService {

    private menuRef = this.db.list<Menu>('menu');

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {

    }

    getMenu() {
        return this.menuRef;
    }
}
```

In the homepage.ts I call the constructor to get data like this:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public dataService: DataServiceProvider, private menuService: MenuService) {


this.menu = this.menuService.getMenu().snapshotChanges()
.map(
  changes => {
    return changes.map(
      c => ({
        key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()
      }))
  }
);
```

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "firebase": "^4.9.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
this.db.list<Menu>('menu');
```

`db.list` returns an array, and you are later, in `snapshotChanges()`, trying to assign it to an object. You should use:

```
this.db.Object<Menu>('menu');
```